# "quick on the draw" vs "quick to draw"

Tags: difference

These two seem to stand for `be quick to the uptake`:

1. `quick on the draw`
2. `quick to draw`

Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: Can you give me an example situation that you would like to use these two phrases interchangably.  I'd be happy to see if these would mean the same in that context if this is what you mean by 'interchangable'.

Comment: @amblina I had "He is quick to draw" and "He is quick on the draw" in mind, thinking that both phases stand to qualify a person.

Comment: OK, if you were describing someone to me and said 'he was quick to draw' I would think he was impulsive in a negative sense.  If you said 'he is quick on the draw' it would be more neutral or complementary depending on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the sentence or what you wish to convey.  The short answer is: that the first is an idiom that has meanings which are more general and are understood by people who know the idiom while the second is usually used in conjunction with what a person is **drawing** (verb) and so is usually more specific.

> **Quick on the draw**

This is an idiom that, for the most part, means what you have said and can mean something positive (i.e. someone is quick as in clever) or it can be negative (i.e. quick to act/judge, impulsive etc).  Here **draw** is a noun.

> **Quick to draw**

Here **draw** is used as a verb.  To my knowledge, **quick to draw** is not an idiom, at least in British English.  If you find 'quick to draw' in a sentence, it's usually something along the lines of:

> She was **quick to draw** conclusions.
>
> She was **quick to draw** attention to the graph.
>
> She was **quick to draw** her weapon.

None of which are idioms but stating something relatively clearly, be it literally or metaphorically.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom **Quick on the draw** mostly means **Able to react quickly** and is used in situations that someone's reaction on something impresses you or causes notable results for him/her. these reaction and/or results could be both positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @amblina's answer, the idiom *"Quick on the draw"* is based on a person's ability to take out (to draw) and shoot a gun immediately (quickly). Another idiom with the same meaning is "[Quick on the trigger"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/quick+on+the+trigger).

As for the ["Quick on the uptake"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/quick+on+the+uptake) idiom, meaning "quick to understand or learn something", it's based on the meaning of the noun "uptake" as a process of taking up/using up/consuming.

So, the difference in the meanings of the idioms, slight as it may seem, is quite noticable